# What is ItemCommand and ItemDatabound of a Data Representation Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Please Explain with example ItemCommand and ItemDatabound of a Data Representation Control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx) is an event that fires once on your server for every record bound to the control.  [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx) is the event that will fire if you click a command button that is associated with the record.

Answer (score 1):

These are events associated with data driven server controls.

ItemDataBound is fired everytime a new item is binded to your data control.

ItemCommand is fired when the command event for a Button or LinkButton or ImageButton inside the data control is used.